# Auto Scan at set intervals and populate SharePoint 2010 List

Tags: 2010, list, updatelistitems, custom-timer-job

Hi can anyone Help me!

I want something that I am able to select a different SharePoint List every week.
within that list select the columns that apply (Monday to Friday or just monday),
I then need it to scan at set intervals(Seconds) the columns selected.
when it detects an blank entry, in one or all of the columns selected.
It will inputs some data in to that field automatically

is this even possible?

Thanks

maddie

Answer (score 1):

Yon can use the Timer job for this requirement.

- Place all your configuration in one list
- Configure the timer job at time you need to run
- write the custom code  as per your requirement

Please find the below link  for step by step walkthrough
[Custom Timer Job in SharePoint 2010](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/custom-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2010/)